# react firebase cannot import db from firebase-config.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need your help. I am trying to import db from the firebase-config.js file where i have setup everything. but I get this error message..

> ERROR in ./src/App.js 7:0-32
> Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package /Users/ispasdaniel/Documents/react-firebase-todo-app/node_modules/firebase (see exports field in /Users/ispasdaniel/Documents/react-firebase-todo-app/node_modules/firebase/package.json)

this is my firebase-config.js

```
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "*********",
  authDomain: "*********",
  projectId: "*********",
  storageBucket: "*********",
  messagingSenderId: "*********",
  appId: "*********",
};

// Use this to initialize the firebase App
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { db };
```

and this is how i import it to my App.js file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import firebase from "firebase";
import "./App.css";
import { db } from "./firebase-config.js";

function App() {
  const [todoInput, setTodoInput] = useState("");

  const addTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    db.collection("todos").add({
      inprogress: true,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimeStamp(),
      todo: todoInput,
    });
  };
```

Comment: Hi @ispasDani, have you checked my posted answer? Also, did you check the posted comment of Dharmaraj for the follow-up question? Let us know if you have any clarifications or questions. Lastly, see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer I figured out. I was using two different versions of Firebase.

Comment: And I cannot UpVote the answers because my reputation is lower then 15..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import `serverTimestamp()` directly from Firestore Modular SDK as shown below:

```
// Remove this import
// import firebase from "firebase";

import { serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

db.collection("todos").add({
  inprogress: true,
  timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
  todo: todoInput,
});
```

Comment: thank you! but I still get this error... Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: @ispasDani did you remove the older import? Also try restarting the React dev server. If the issue still persists, are you sure it's coming from same place?

Comment: It was my mistake, I was using two different versions of Firebase. In my firebase-config.js I was setting everything like Firebase recommended, but in my App.js I was writing code like I've learned from the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have installed the latest version of your Firebase, you can run this command:

`npm i firebase@latest`

Upon checking your codes, you've used two different versions in your `firebase-config.js` (you used the web version 9) and `app.js` (web version 8) that's why you encountered your error.

You can follow the Firebase documentation in [adding a document for web version 9](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document), and use what @Dharmaraj stated in importing `serverTimestamp()` directly:

```
// Remove this import
// import firebase from "firebase";
import { collection, addDoc, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "user"), {
  inprogress: true,
  timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
  todo: todoInput,
});
```

Comment: That was the problem. In my App.js I was writing the code like I have learned from the first time when I've tried it...